# Pre send script in groovy for jenkins

Tags: groovy, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

i have two dependent jobs. i need help for groovy script in jenkins, for writing pre send script for `email-ext` plugin.

i want to check whether buid reason is upstream cause, then set cancel `variable=true`

But i don't know how to write if condition in groovy for jenkins..For seperate jobs, will there be any seperate classes in jenkins(so i can create instance and call upstream cause)

is there any way to check build cause of downstream job is due to  upstream..

Please help me on this code snippet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Build.getCauses()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getCauses%28%29) method. It will return a list of causes for the build. Loop over it and check if there is an object of [hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html) among them.

To get the build object, use the following code snippet:

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
```

FYI, here is a link to the complete [Jenkins Module API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).